# Ruby on Rails - rspec failing 1 example with spork but working without it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org, spork

I am very new to RoR and am following the Rails Tutorials. I created a Pages controller and first created just Home and Contact pages and ran the test. Both the examples passed. Next, I manually added a third 'about' page and made the appropriate changes. However, the third 'about' example is failing with spork running. Once I closed spork, the examples passed.
Here is the output with spork running:

```
Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:21 # PagesController GET 'about' returns http success

Randomized with seed 15477
```

Here is my pages_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do 
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do 
    it "returns http success" do 
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success 
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

    describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

Added this line to routes.rb :

```
  get "pages/about"
```

Added this line to pages_controller.rb:

```
  def about
  end
```

And added the about.html.erb in the views folder.

Also, the url- localhost:3000/pages/about works from the browser.
I am not sure why this example is failing.

Comment: Is there no stack trace?

Comment: I am not really sure how to get the stack trace. The page is coming up in the browser. Like I said, I am new to RoR.

Comment: @prusswan , Yes, I am using Spork. Is that the problem? Also, wanted to let you know that I am using Linux Mint 12

Comment: Ok so all 3 examples are passing if I run rspec without spork. Although it is working now, why is it not working with spork?

Comment: What is all the output that comes out at the console when the example fails?

Comment: Just the error message that I mentioned above - Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:21

Comment: I have left using spork for now and have move on with the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already running spork and attempt to make changes to the routes, those changes will not be reflected until spork has been restarted. This is most likely the cause of that particular test failure.